# Why am I getting an empty matrix from svmpredict?

Tags: svm, matlab, libsvm

I want to make predictions from a simple time series. The observations `y=[11,22,33,44,55,66,77,88,99,110]` and at time `x=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]`. I am using epsilon-SVR from libsvm toolbox. My code is as follows:

```
x1 = (1:7)'; #' training set
y1 = [11, 22, 33, 44, 55, 66, 77]'; #' observations from time series
options = ' -s 3 -t 2 -c 100 -g 0.05 -p 0.0003 ';
model = svmtrain(y1, x1, options)
x2 = (8:10)'; #' test set
y2 = [88, 99, 110]'; #' hidden values that are not used for training
[y2_predicted, accuracy] = svmpredict(y2, x2, model)
```

But the `svmpredict` function is giving me null output as shown below:

```
y2_predicted =
     []
accuracy =
     []
```

Comment: Is your data limited to this small number of data examples? By the way: Be careful how you sample your training and test dataset. You seem to have selected the last observations from your data as testset, I think it is better to sample randomly to prevent order related effects.

Comment: Surely `y2` should not be an input to `svmpredict`? -- nevermind, http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/116420-how-to-use-svmpredict-libsvm has cleared up my question

Comment: Your MATLAB syntax is wrong - `x1 = (1:7)'; #' training set` is not valid MATLAB. `x1 = (1:7)'; % 'training set` is, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you're not getting output predictions is that you are calling `svmpredict` incorrectly. There are two ways to call it:

```
[predicted_label, accuracy, decision_values/prob_estimates] = svmpredict(testing_label_vector, testing_instance_matrix, model, 'libsvm_options')
[predicted_label] = svmpredict(testing_label_vector, testing_instance_matrix, model, 'libsvm_options'
```

With the output of one argument and of 3, but not 2. So to fix your problem, you can do:

```
[y2_pred, accuracy, ~] = svmpredict(y2, x2, model)
```

if you don't care about the decision values. If you do, then

```
[y2_pred, accuracy, decision_values] = svmpredict(y2, x2, model)
```